Add CSS class to Sphinx-generated anchor span
With this RST file:
.. cssclass:: myclass
.. _important:

Something really important
--------------------------

...and this call:
sphinx-build -C ./ ./html ./index.rst

...the following HTML results:
<section class="myclass" id="something-really-important">
  <span id="important"></span>
  <h1>Something really important</h1>
</section>

It would be really convenient for me if Sphinx could place the class="myclass" into the span element, instead of into the section element.
Is that possible?

There is no reStructuredText syntax or Docutils/Sphinx setting that allows to add a custom class on the auxiliary span holding an alias ID.

This span is added by the HTML writer component because the section has two IDs: the auto-generated "something-really-important" and the ID set by the internal hyperlink target .. _important:.
The Docutils native XML would look like
    <target refid="important"></target>
    <section classes="myclass" ids="something-really-important important" names="something\ really\ important important">
        <title>Something really important</title>
    </section>

but HTML does not support more than one ID per element, so a workaround is required.

CSS allows you to identify such <span> by using something like
section.myclass span {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}


Humm... good to know. In my case, I'm not trying to select the element. It is being selected by the site in which the Sphinx-generated docs are being plugged into. It would be nice if I could add a class to that Sphinx-generated span.
